# How to read a big file list from a textfile to form a query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have this query which I have to run multiple times in excel and i need to change the filelists in it.

```
   select * from files 
   where 
   filename in ('filename1','filename2')
```

so I have a TEMP in my query filename in TEMP and I want to loop and get the result for all filelists. My onlyproblem is reading .txt into the TEMP and executing the query once for all filenames in the txt file. i know how to read files line by line so that didn't help.

my text files which I want to read the lists from are like

filename1
filename2
.
.
.
.
filename15000

yes some big numbers.

```
    dim filelist as string
    dim filelistpath as string
    sqlstring = "select count(*) from files where  filename in TEMP"
    filelistpath = "c:\"

    open filelistpath for input as #1
    do while not EOF(1)
    line input #1,text
    'here i should construct my file list to replace the TEMP below, how ?
    loop
    close #1 
    sqlstring = replace(sqlstring,TEMP, filelist)

    set rs = conn.execute(sqlstring)

    'here i want to write the result to my excel sheet, how ?
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing.  Please provide the code of what you have already tried so we can better sort out what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: i will do that shortly,coz its on my pendrive and I am on my way home :)

Comment: is there a way to just read the whole text file into a variant or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the text and just read it like that as a whole

```
Function GetText(sFile As String) As String
   Dim nSourceFile As Integer, sText As String

 ''Close any open text files
  Close

  ''Get the number of the next free text file
   nSourceFile = FreeFile

  ''Write the entire file to sText
   Open sFile For Input As #nSourceFile
   sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
   Close

   GetText = sText
   End Function
```